# Rocket Chat - Restrict user visibility outside team/group

Tags: rocket.chat

In my requirement, I am supposed to create a few teams (groups) and assign users to those groups.
Users cannot see any user other than the users in assigned groups. How to achieve this?

Tried to achieve this with permissions, but no option found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to restrict user from accessing the users exist outside the current room or channel then please to the settings and you will find there a permission tab, you can set it from there. thank you.